# I want to suppress before two zeros and include zeros before values with two digits

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to suppress before two zeros and include zeros before values with two digits.

[image]

How to do the logic kindly help me on this.

Comment: Do you want to do this in JavaScript or C#? You've tagged both languages

Comment: In C#, the documentation contains a guide on exactly how to do this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros

Comment: The question was about padding a _**string**_ with leading zeros to a length of 3, not a numeric value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in one line in C#:

```
string stringValue = "056";

string newStringValue = int.Parse(stringValue).ToString("000");
```

`int.Parse()` will automatically strip the leading zeroes and give you an int, and the "000" format in `.ToString` will ensure the resulting string is always three digits and pad with leading zeroes if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript solution:

`/^([0]{0,})/` regex replaces all leading contiguous zeros. Then we just pad it to length 3 with an initial zero.

```js
const numbers = ['56', '056', '0056', '00056'];

const leadingZero = (nums) => {
  return nums.map((num) => {
    if (!num?.length) throw new Error();
    return removeContigiousLeadingZeros(num);
  });
};

const removeContigiousLeadingZeros = (num) => {
  return num.replace(/^([0]{0,})/, '0')
};

console.log(leadingZero(numbers));
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript (or any other language), just add enough leading zeros to ensure you have a length of 3,  and then take the rightmost 3 characters:

```
const n  = '56';
const padded = n.padStart(3,'0').slice(-3) ;
// padded = '056'
```

It's not much different in C#, except that you need an explicit intermediate (because you need that string's length):

```
string n = '56';
string t = n.PadLeft(3,'0') ;
string padded = t.SubString( t.Length-3 ) ;
```